# "java: package org.apache.cordova does not exist" when compliling Cordova in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, cordova, installation, android-studio

New to android dev world and am just getting started here, well trying to anyway. I've downloaded Cordova (2.8, might need to upgrade this), Java JDK (1.7), and the new Android Studio, the Andriod SDK, installed all the 4.x packages with that, and installed ant (1.9.2).

Everything seems to be working as far as that goes. Problem is when I can create a Cordova project, from the command line, load it up in Studio using the import feature, not tweaking anything, just accepting (as I read to do so on some blog out there) and everything seems to load ok and the project is there in Studio, until I try to make it. At this point, I get and error "java: package org.apache.cordova does not exist" This is followed by several other errors, which I feel may be related. I'm not nor am I trying to do anything fancy here, just get the stock up and running.

Anybody know what I'm missing? Do I need to copy a file somewhere or compile something extra? Or am I using the wrong version of something? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found after hours of searching and trial and error (although mostly errors) I came to find that it was all due to missing the cordova-*.jar file. which needed to be built using the `ant jar` in the framework folder of my android cordova directory. This step had been majorly left out of a ton of documentation. Once built, I simply copied this into the 'libs' folder of my project and everything loaded up and ran, although I did get a warning about depreciated project from the compiler, creating an ant build and selecting 'external compiler' fixed this warning.

Comment: This solution also solved failures I had with the phonegap 3.0 Command Line Interface, when building for android.  Once the cordova-*.jar was in place, "phonegap local run android" worked properly.

Comment: Please can you explain further how the cordova-*.jar is created and where to find it once created?

Comment: This looks like it finally got documented, this should help you out on how to build the cordova-*.jar file (steps #1 and #2) [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html)

Comment: Yea the `framework/` folder doesn't seem to exist anymore. There is a `CordovaLib/` folder. But running `ant jar` in there fails.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses Gradle project layout. This means main java files should be in /src/main/java. If Cordova generates different structure (it looks like it is old Ant structure) you need to add its source folders to build.gradle

```
android {
...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                include 'some/wanted/package/**'
                include 'another/wanted/package/**'
                exclude 'some/unwanted/package/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the file sits:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for being such a Noob, but I don't understand where to put this.

Comment: I added it into the main .java file but the compiler didn't like it. I searched the project for sourceSets, other includes and the android keyword but couldn't find them.

Comment: add it to build.gradle file. there are two files named like that. Use the one which is inside module, not the one in the root of the project. That file should already have android {} closure.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't have that file and the structure is really different than what you've shown. I have a build.xml file. Maybe when I import the Cordova project, I'm supposed to use the Gradle layout in step 2? I did try that, but I don't have Gradle installed (it's not in the Cordova instructions). Is that something I need to be installing as well?

Comment: so the problem is that your project is not Android Studio project at all. You have two options. Go with Eclipse/ADT or create new project in Android studio and add all cordova sources. Java files to /src/main/java, res to /src/main/res, manifest to /src/main