# Cordova: Android studio emulator does not work

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed Android studio on my mashine and imported a project created with cordova using the prompt comand. Now, If I select the index.html of the folder called android and try to run the emulator I get following errors. I am using the latest version of Cordova 4.3.0.

```
Error:(23, 1) error: package org.apache.cordova does not exist
Error:(25, 35) error: cannot find symbol class CordovaActivity
Error:(27, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a        supertype
Error:(30, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(31, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable super
Error:(33, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable launchUrl
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Check these solutions:

1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283180/java-package-org-apache-cordova-does-not-exist-when-compliling-cordova-in-and

2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134420/package-org-apache-cordova-does-not-exist

3)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011405/java-package-org-apache-cordova-does-not-exist-when-compiling-phonegap-projec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling cordova and if that doesnt work try rinstalling android studio

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled both, but I have the same problem.

Comment: uuhhm check your firewall maybe that will help